# jquery not finding class on span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get the html below rendered on my webesite

```
<a class="k-grid-filter k-state-active" href="#" tabindex="-1"><span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
```

I am trying to attach a click handler to the span that is displayed but I cannot get the break-point to hit?

My javascript code is below:

```
$(document).on("click", ".k-icon .k-filter", function () {
    debugger;
});
```

Is there something I have missed here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

remove space between selector `.k-icon` and `.k-filter`

```
$(document).on("click", ".k-icon.k-filter", function () {
    debugger;
});
```

> if you give space between selector then it considers the second
>   selector as a child.

Comment: if you give space between selector then it considers the second selector as a child.

Comment: I cant find a source but I think I remember browser compatibility issues when selecting elements by specifying multiple class names like this, can anybody confirm whether that is a thing?

Comment: All good current browsers support this as well as IE back to version 7.

Comment: @patelarpan Glad you didn't include IE in the 'good current browsers' category :)

Comment: @Gezzasa,  I can't stop laughing at that :):)

Answer (score -1):

To attach a click handler to your span, you can do it the following way.

1. Add an ID to the span element (assume `'span-id'` is the ID here) and bind using an ID

   ```
   $('#span-id').on('click', function() {
     debugger;
   });
   ```
2. In case you absolutely want to select by combination of class names, you need to specify the classnames without spaces, as follows

   ```
   $('.k-icon.k-filter').on('click', function() {
     debugger;
   });
   ```

Comment: No need for ID's,. He targeted the span incorrectly with the space inbetween.

Comment: Yes. Of course he can do it by using classes. I was suggesting to use ID since thats the better way to select a single element. @Gezzasa

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML ELEMENTS STRUCTURE define ( classes place besides elements) :

```
|-- a  .k-grid-filter .k-state-active
|   |-- span  .k-icon .k-filter
```

And JQuery elements binding Classes define below(nesting lebel) :

```
|-- .k-icon 
|   |-- .k-filter
```

class `'.k-filter'` child of `'.k-icon'`, so your's debugger not working in JQuery.

Correct JQuery Code :

```
$(document).on("click", ".k-icon.k-filter", function () {
    debugger;
});

`
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".k-icon.k-filter", function () {
        debugger;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="k-grid-filter k-state-active" href="#" tabindex="-1">
     <span class="k-icon k-filter">debugger</span>
</a>
```